# Logstash jdbc input does not retry as setup

Tags: logstash

I am using logstash to transfer data from postgresql to mysql.

There are 10 configure files in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` and I run logstash as a service by the command `systemctl start logstash`.

I have setup the **retry** configure `connection_retry_attempts`  and `connection_retry_attempts_wait_time`  (retry 10 times every 2 mins) as shown below:

```
input {
    jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/lib/postgresql-42.2.14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_page_size => "50000"
    connection_retry_attempts => 10
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 120
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxx"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "xxx"
    jdbc_default_timezone => "UTC"
    statement => "select ... from ... where ... and  login_time >= :sql_last_value "
    tracking_column => "login_time"
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    use_column_value => true
    last_run_metadata_path => "/home/data/logs/..."
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    type => "xxx"
    }
  }
```

However, the setup did not work as expected. A connection error occured, 8/10 table tranfer stopped only 2 still worked. I restart the logstash service and fixed it. But according to the log, there's not event retry attemp after the connection failure.

How to make the jdbc input automatically retry connect? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
[2022-06-07T18:08:03,763][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main] Unable to connect to database. Trying again {:error_message=>"Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: The connection attempt failed."}
[2022-06-07T18:10:03,914][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main] (0.015812s) SELECT CAST(current_setting('server_version_num') AS integer) AS v
[2022-06-07T18:10:03,940][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main] (0.024598s) SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM (select * from xxx where added_time >= '2022-06-06 11:47:00' and added_time >= '2022-06-07 10:06:48.221000+0000' ) AS "t1" LIMIT 1
```